# GoToWebinar API missing data for attendees calls

Tags: php, api, rest, citrix

**Edit/Solution: PHP json_decode was converting and rounding the session ID's to a float.**

I am making several API calls that are getting no data returned, despite what I believe to be the correct call to the GoToWebinar API service and the data showing up in the reports downloadable through the GoTo Admin Panel.

Let me start by saying I have my OAuth Token, and I am able to perform many API calls as outlined in their documentation.

Here is an example of a call to ["Get Attendees From All Webinar Sessions"](https://developer.citrixonline.com/api/gotowebinar-rest-api/apimethod/get-attendees-all-webinar-sessions) and a subsequent response (parsed in PHP):

**Call URL:**

> api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/300000000000374239/webinars/524374823/attendees

**Response:**

```
(int) 0 => array(
    'registrantKey' => (int) 106396902,
    'sessionKey' => (float) 300000000011857664,
    'firstName' => 'xxx',
    'lastName' => 'xxx',
    'email' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
    'attendanceTimeInSeconds' => (int) 1597,
    'attendance' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'leaveTime' => '2014-11-06T20:22:48Z',
            'joinTime' => '2014-11-06T19:56:11Z'
        )
    )
```

As you can see, it's working fine right there.

Now, when I try to call ["Get Attendee Questions"](https://developer.citrixonline.com/api/gotowebinar-rest-api/apimethod/get-attendee-questions), I am getting an empty object being returned.

**Call URL:**

> api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/300000000000374239/webinars/524374823/sessions/300000000011857664/attendees/106396902/questions

**Response:**

```
'[]'
```

The response is the raw response from CURL without any additional processing. As you will see, the registrantKey and sessionKey match what is in the return from the first call. Additionally, the first call would not have worked without the correct webinarKey.

For further proof, I just want to share data from a report that comes from GoToWebinar. The date stamps within it match exactly.

> **Join Time Nov 06, 2014 02:56 PM EST**
>
> In Session Duration* (minutes) 26.62
>
> **Leave Time Nov 06, 2014 03:22 PM EST**
>
> Registration Q & A
>
> Q: Type of business?
>
> A:
>
> **Questions Asked by Attendee**
>
> **Q: Thank you Audrey.**
>
> **A: --unanswered--**
>
> Poll Questions
>
> Q: To continue the digital conversation, you have several options:
>
> A: Other (use the Questions window)
>
> Post Session Survey Questions
>
> Q: Still have questions? Please enter them below and we will contact you back shortly.
>
> A: Thank you. You have answered all my questions at this time.

So, I am really confused by all of this. I haven't found anything in the documentation, and Google searches haven't gotten me anywhere.